# Capitalize first letter of every word, and keep the rest in lowercase

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript [here](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/title-case-a-sentence#?solution=function%20titleCase%28str%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20arrayify%20%3D%20str.split%28%27%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20arrayify.forEach%28function%28arrayify%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%20x%20%3C%20arrayify%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20caps%20%3D%20current[x]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20caps%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AtitleCase%28%22I%27m%20a%20little%20tea%20pot%22%29%3B). My task as of right now is to take a given string and capitalize the beginning of each word, and IF the rest of the word is already caps, put it into lowercase.

What I have so far:

```
function titleCase(str){
    var arrayify = str.split('');
    arrayify.forEach(function(current, index){
        for (var x = 0; x < current; x++){
            var caps = current[x];
            return caps;
        } 
    });
}
```

My test strings:

- `I'm a little tea pot`
- `sHoRt AnD sToUt`
- `HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT`

What I've tried:

```
function titleCase(str){
   str.split(' ').map(s => chartAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join(' '); 
}
```

---

```
function titleCase(str){
     return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.chartAt(0).toUpperCase} + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};
```

Everytime I use the `=>` it tells me that I need `esversion:6` in order to run it.

My question, what am I doing wrong, and what would be the most idiomatic way to go about doing this?

Pictures to prove I'm not crazy:

[image]

Comment: First `titleCase` has no `return` statement and is missing the `.toLowerCase()` call. Second one forgot the `()` after `.toUpperCase`. They both have `chartAt(0)` instead of `charAt(0)`.

Comment: @imvain2 None of those answers work..

Comment: `reference charAt(0) is not defined` @squint

Comment: Oh, you're calling it on nothing. it should be `s.charAt(0)`.

Comment: @squint That's what I meant sorry.

Comment: It's not like I pointed that out or anything

Comment: @13aal: The second one also has an extra `}` in the middle, and is calling `.replace()` on `this` instead of `str`.

Comment: @squint After `toUpperCase`?

Comment: The `0 is read-only` is because strings are immutable, so you can't mutate individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detail the issues with your existing solutions, they almost work but have the following problems:

```
function titleCase(str){
   // missing `s.`--------v    v---extra "t" 
   str.split(' ').map(s => chartAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join(' '); 
//^---missing return statement |---missing toLowerCase() call---^
}
```

---

```
function titleCase(str) {
     // -----v--should be `str`
     return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
       // ------------v--extra "t" |----v--- extra "}"
       return txt.chartAt(0).toUpperCase} + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
       // ---missing `()` -------------^
     });
};
```

---

Here are the fixed versions:

```
function titleCase(str){
   return str.split(' ').map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ');
}
```

---

```
function titleCase(str) {
     return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
       return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
     });
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what happened but it worked so thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the function so instead of returning in the `forEach` loop it appends the result onto an existing variable to be returned at the end.

Get the character at the start of each array value, change it to uppercase and then add it to the rest of the value which has been converted to lowercase.

**Example**:

```
function titleCase(str){
    var arrayify = str.split(' ');
    var result = '';
    arrayify.forEach(function(item) {
        result += item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase() + ' ';
    });
    return result.slice(0, -1); // remove last whitespace
}
```